# Firestore cannot get path onsnapshot

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am listening to changes on the database for [collection_group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) 
I cannot access ref (which has path) of a DocumentSnapshot I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DocumentSnapshot' object has no attribute 'ref'
```

Here is my code:

```
doc_ref = firestore_db.collection_group(u'collection_name')
doc_ref.on_snapshot(self.__get_snapshot(args))
```

This is my __get_snapshot method:

```
def __get_snapshot(self, args):
    def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
        for doc in doc_snapshot: #crashes
            print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.ref))
        for change in changes:
            if(change.type.name == "MODIFIED"):
                print(change.document.ref) #crashes
                print(change.document.get("field"))#this works fine
return on_snapshot
```

Comment: Link to how on snapshot works: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API documentation for [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot) says that the reference of the document can be found in its [reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot.reference) property.  So you will want to use this: `doc.reference`.

Comment: Thank you I must have been looking at wrong documentation

Comment: I think you should post a new question explaining what's now not working the way you expect.